# Read from file: C to C++

Tags: c++, c, input, io, inputstream

I've been trying to read a file in `C/C++` and was able to do so for `C` but am facing some problems with `C++`.

Background: The file I'm trying to read has the following structure

```
i = %3d; j = %3d; a = %3d; b = %3d;
i = %3d; j = %3d; a = %3d; b = %3d;
...
```

The code I have which works in `C` is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#define MAXSIZE 32

int main()
{
    FILE* inputfile = fopen("temp.txt","r");
    int i,j,a,b;

    while (!feof(inputfile))
    {
        fscanf(inputfile,
            "i = %3d; "
            "j = %3d; "
            "a = %3d; "
            "b = %3d;\n",
            &i, &j, &a, &b);

        printf("%3d %3d %3d %3d\n", i,j,a,b);
    }

    fclose(inputfile);
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to write this program in `C++` I've tried:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile( "temp.txt" ,ios::in);
    int i,j,a,b;

    while (!std::cin.eof())
    {
        inputfile >> "i = " >> i >> "; j = " >> j >> "; a = " >> a >> "; b = " >> b >> ";\n";
        printf("%3d %3d %3d %3d\n", i,j,a,b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not too sure how I should go about formatting
`inputfile >> "i = " >> i >> "; j = " >> j >> "; a = " >> a >> "; b = " >> b >> ";\n";`
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** The problem I'm facing is that the pernultimate line is not formatted in the right way. Because my file is in the form stated in the question, I cannot write `inputfile >> i >> j >> a >> b;`.

Comment: so what problem are you facing?

Comment: Do you really need to verify the presence of the `i = `, `j = `, and so on, or is it all right to just ignore them and read the numbers?

Comment: @jayeshbhoi Hi, I've edited the question, hope that clears up the focus of the question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I've tried `inputfile >> i >> j >> a >> b;`, got an infinite loop with constant output `0  -2 937351794 2007600341`. I think the lack of `\n` meant it did not move to the next line.

Comment: @BlackAdder: So how *is* that penultimate line formatted? Hard to advise how to read data without a clue of what we're really supposed to be reading.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Terribly sorry if I'm unclear. The question is exactly that: How to format the pernultimate line? My data is in a file and is of the form `i = 0; j = 1; a = 100; b = 217;` for example. And I would like to read them line by line. But `inputfile >> i >> j >> a >> b;` would not work because of the `i = ` characters which are not numbers.

Comment: `while (!feof(...))` is wrong in both C and C++. Try `while(fscanf(...) != EOF)` or `while (inputfile >> ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get away with just ignoring the `i =`, `j =` and so on, and just need to read the numbers, one possibility would be to create a ctype facet that classifies those characters as white space. Imbue the stream with a locale that includes that facet, and just read your numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> {
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

class record {
    int i, j, a, b;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, record &r) {
        return is >> r.i >> r.j >> r.a >> r.b;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, record const &r) {
        return os << r.i << "\t" << r.j << "\t" << r.a << "\t" << r.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::stringstream in("i=1 j = 2 a = 10 b = 20\ni = 3 j = 4 a = 30 b = 40");
    std::locale numbers(std::locale(), new digits_only);
    in.imbue(numbers);

    std::vector<record> records{ std::istream_iterator<record>(in),
                                 std::istream_iterator<record>() };

    std::cout << "i\tj\ta\tb\n";
    for (auto const & r : records)
        std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

As to whether this is better or worse than just using `scanf`, I'd say it's open to some question. It's clearly longer overall. OTOH, a lot of the extra length in the code above is from my deciding to wrap `i`, `j`, `a` and `b` into a structure of their own. Though it's only a guess, my guess is that you *probably* want to do that in any case.

In exchange for some extra length, you get type safety, and if you have several different parts of your code that need to read records like this, a lot more convenience.

Contrary to Ben Voigt's claim, actual testing shows that I/O using iostreams can be completely competitive with C's stdio functions (and faster in some cases). I haven't tested this particular case enough to be sure whether it's faster, slower, or about the same, but I've done enough other testing to say with reasonable certainty that it's far from a foregone conclusion that C's stdio functions will be substantially faster.

Bottom line: it's possible that continuing to use `scanf` is a good choice--but then again, it may not be either.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the original code.  It's better in *every* way:

- It works (except if the file ends with a blank line, see below).
- It is tested.
- It runs faster.
- It is perfectly valid in both C and C++.
- It compiles faster.

However, I will offer one improvement:

```
while (4 == fscanf(inputfile,
        "i = %3d; "
        "j = %3d; "
        "a = %3d; "
        "b = %3d;\n",
        &i, &j, &a, &b))
{
    printf("%3d %3d %3d %3d\n", i,j,a,b);
}
if (!feof(inputfile)) {
    // read failed and the reason wasn't hitting the end of the file
    // maybe you've been keeping track of line numbers and
    // can report where the invalid input was found
}
```

Testing EOF before trying to read is too early.  The EOF flag only gets set after a read hits the end of the file.  If the last successful read actually found the `'\n'`, then EOF won't be set.  The iostreams code had the same bug, in addition to the problem dealing with intervening text.

---

Nota Bene: You'll never notice the speed difference for user input, or even for output to a terminal.  But for file I/O (including redirected stdin or stdout), the stdio.h functions beat iostreams by a lot.

Comment: I was just going to mention the eof/feof thing.  Good call.